# Rails Image Tag Helper

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

Using Rails, I'm fine with the image tag helper in an HTML file but how do I include images in a CSS file. I've tried replacing the url from:

```
background:url('/assets/img/banners/img3.jpg')
```

to...

```
background:url(<%= image_tag "banners/img3.jpg" %>)
```

but this doesn't work. Do I need to change the extension of my css files to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any helpers in CSS, and that's OK; you can specify the path manually and it will always work.

Also remember that paths are relative to the stylesheet itself, not to the HTML document.

Comment: marked as correct because first correct answer and simple. cheers

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your css should have `erb` extension at the end. example: `style.css.erb`. then you can do this

```
.class { background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'image.png' %>) }
```

this will work because asset pipeline automatically evaluates ERB due to the `erb` file extension.n this example, it would make sense to have an image in one of the asset load paths, such as `app/assets/images/image.png`, which would be referenced here. If this image is already available in `public/assets` as a fingerprinted file, then that path is referenced.

Read more at [The Asset Pipeline Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets)

Comment: but what if we are using .scss not .css

Comment: In that case filename would be like `style.css.scss.erb`. Just append `erb` at the end to make sure `asset_path` tags are processed first